# How to solve mismatch error for IF formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I thought the formula was simple enough, but I am receiving a mismatch error. Column M is formatted general and contains text. Columns P:O are formatted for numbers. What's odd is that I don't get a mismatch error with one, simple criteria. It only returns an error when I use the "AND" term.

```
Sub Test()
Dim wsTD As Worksheet
Set wsTD = Sheets("Summary").Range("M2")

With wsTD
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 2 To LastRow
        If (.Cells(i, "M").Value) <> ("A") And (.Cells(i, "M").Value) <> ("B") And (.Cells(i, "M").Value) <> ("C") And (.Cells(i, "M").Value) <> ("D") And (.Cells(i, "M").Value) <> ("E") And (.Cells(i, "M").Value) <> ("F") And (.Cells(i, "M").Value) <> ("G") Then
           .Cells(i, "A").Range("P2") = "O2*.98"
         End If
     Next i
 End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set wsTD = Sheets("Summary").Range("M2")` should be just `Set wsTD = Sheets("Summary")`.

At the moment everything in the `With wsTD` is based off of cell `M2`.

E.g.
`Range("M2").Cells(i,"A").Range("P2")` is referring to cell `AB3` if `i = 1`.

- `Range("M2")` is the starting cell.
- `Cells(1,"A")` refers the first cell in that range - which is `M2`.
- `Range("P2")` is 16 columns across and 2 cells down from the starting range - which is `AB3`.

The cell adding the formula to column P is only adding the text "O2*.98".  To add a formula you'd use:

```
.Cells(i, "P").Formula = "=O2*0.98"
```

This is based on the assumption that you want it on row `i` in column `P`.